# Sharing Public Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

I use a raspberry pi on a boat to log various sensors, and also as a hotspot for sharing Internet on the boat. I have a USB wifi adapter with an external antenna mounted on a mast. I also have a 4G modem, again with with an external antenna, with an Ethernet connection back to the Raspberry pi. I have been able use iptables to create network address translation to share the wifi connections described above on the internal wifi device of the Raspberry Pi 3.

However, on some public wifi hotspots the usb wifi device keeps getting disconnected. My research has shown that the public wifi AP is probably looking at the MAC address of the devices connected to my local hotspot and seeing that it does not match the MAC address of the USB device to which it authenticated, and so de-authenticates the USB device.

I understand that either WDS or 4 address mode could be used if I had control over the Public AP which has the wifi connection, but that is clearly not possible.

I explored the use of ebtables, but you cannot attach a STA wifi device to a virtual bridge unless it is using 4 Address mode.

I feel sure it must be possible to emulate what is described in the instructions of a TP link wifi extender:

"When Range Extender is working in Universal Mode:

In this mode, Range Extender will replace all its clients’ MAC addresses with RE’s own MAC address"

I can find nothing that describes how to achieve that with a linux distribution.

If anyone knows how I could achieve what is described by the Universal Mode above I would be grateful.

Alternatively if there is some way of authenticating each client to my local hotspot to the public wifi AP ?

Comment: Your question appears to be missing a crucial detail: How exactly does *another* WiFi network even come into play? You only described a basic NAT router setup to share your 4G internet. How do you connect to a hotspot? Why not just use NAT?

Comment: The external usb wifi device (wlan0) of the arm, in managed mode connects to the external public hotspot.  The internal wifi of the arm is in master mode (wlan1) as a hotspot.  The devices on board connect to the arm hotspot as they are not able to see the public hotspot due to lack of signal strength. I do use NAT, however, with NAT the public AP, sees the device which is connected to wlan1 AP has a different mac address to that which was authenticated (wlan0) so I believe it then de-authenticates wlan0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot (reliably) use a bridged mode with APs you don’t control. Using repeater mode (essentially 1:1 NAT of MAC addresses) would require non-trivial efforts. It would also mean you’d have to log in separately on each device.

Instead, what you want is NAT. The easiest solution is to just use something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Additionally, you’ll have to make sure your internal network uses a different IP subnet so as not to cause conflicts.

With NAT, you have different network segments. The hotspot will never know about the devices that hide behind your RasPi. It will not see any MAC addresses but wlan0’s. You will only have to log in once per connection.

Comment: I am already using NAT - and it often works flawlessly, but in another marina with a different public AP (no key), it fails.   I understand this is because 802.11 normally uses a 3 address frame which means the source station mac carries through to the final access point, thus giving it opportunity to check the source address and if it does not match the station it actually authenticated it has opportunity to reject those frames and or the connection.  I just thought on Linux there might be a way round this.

Comment: No, that’s wrong. A wireless *station* sends frames only for itself. It *cannot* send frames on behalf of other hosts. The third address is the target behind the *access point*. Different network segments mean MAC addresses don’t travel. Simple as that.

Comment: Thank you - with this information I was able to determine my issue was around insufficient power for the wifi adapter where an AP was close to the adapter wlan1 the adapter did not draw as much power as when an AP was further away. Once I used a powered USB hub - problem solved.

Comment: Ah yes, the maximum feasible length of a USB cable is 5 meters. However, this may already be too much for high-current devices like radios.